# php download code works for pdf but not zip

Tags: php, download, zip, exe

I've been successfully downloading pdf files with this code. I'm using the identical code to download a zip file containing an exe (just changing the file name and changing the the mime type to application/zip), and I'm getting this error when I try to open the downloaded file:
"Windows cannot open the folder.
The Compressed (zipped) Folder '[filename]' is invalid"

I verified that the original uncompressed file runs, and also I can successfully unzip the folder on my laptop and run the exe.

I also downloaded the zip file from my website through Filezilla to a temp folder, unzipped and ran it, to make sure there was no problem with the upload.

It's a 70 MB file, so I tried downloading a 65 kb zipped exe --- same error.

I added header("Content-Length: " . $file_size), even though the pdfs were downloading fine without it --- same error.

I tried application/octet-stream --- same error.

Any ideas? Any suggestions appreciated.

```
$file_size  = filesize($file_path);  
$file = @fopen($file_path,"r"); 
if ($file) 
{
    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\""); 
    //header("Content-Length: " . $file_size); 
    header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);


    set_time_limit(0);
    fseek($file, 0);

    while(!feof($file)) 
    {
        print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        if (connection_status()!=0) 
        {
            @fclose($file);
            exit;
        }           
    }
    @fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows XP ? and what protocol? http or https?

Comment: and why are you reading the zip-flie chunked? can't do readfile($zipfile) the task?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, http

Comment: I found this code here http://www.media-division.com/the-right-way-to-handle-file-downloads-in-php/ and its purpose is to provide byte range support. Maybe it's overkill but it's doing no harm so I left it.

Comment: I also tried downloading an uncompressed exe and I got this error when I clicked on the downloaded file: "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check you computer system infromation to see whether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

Answer (score 0):

A problem may be that your `php_execution_time` is to low and it aborts before the zip is downloaded.
Check if the size of the zip is the same size as on the server.

or activate the mod_xsendfile in Apache and set the header:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $filename");
```

Comment: The size of the file on the server is 71,612,221. The downloaded file is 71,612,427. Any ideas what that could mean?